# Connect to web API with certificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, ssl, asp.net-web-api, web

I want to connect to third party API from my web application. They have given me a certificate file(.p12) and two .pem files.One with certificate information and one with private key.

The issue is when i try to connect to the API, it gives me an error saying 'Signature and/or certificate invalid'. This is how I added the certificate to my http request.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest();
        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate("<location>","<password>");
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

I want to know what is missing in here. And is there any other way to add certificate to web request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message says the certificate is invalid.  So why are you looking for another way to attach a certificate to the request?  Did you maybe check the documentation for `X509Certificate`, where it says:  "ASN.1 DER is the only certificate format supported by this class.  For most scenarios, you should use the X509Certificate2 class instead."

Comment: @Amy thanks, I will try that. Any idea about .pem files

Comment: I have lots of ideas about .pem files.